# Type Any does not conform to protocol Sequence

Tags: swift, xcode, protocols, sequence

I'm using the Github project [MMSCameraViewController](https://github.com/miller-ms/MMSCameraViewController) in a project and since the recent Xcode 8.3 update the compiler throws the error:

**/MMSCameraViewController/Classes/MMSCameraViewController.swift:448:42: Type '[Any]!!' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'**

```
for port in (connection as AnyObject).inputPorts { // <----- this line throws error
   if (port as! AVCaptureInputPort).mediaType == AVMediaTypeVideo {
       videoConnection = connection as! AVCaptureConnection
       break connectionloop
   }
}
```

I've search the other posts about type-any-sequence posts appearing here recently, but none of that helped me (and I'm new to Swift). Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because AnyObject is not what you want, error is really clear.

```
for port in (connection as! AVCaptureConnection).inputPorts {
     if (port as! AVCaptureInputPort).mediaType == AVMediaTypeVideo {
            videoConnection = connection as! AVCaptureConnection
            break connectionloop
     }
}
```

Library should go through every port so AnyObject does not have any

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your connection is AVCaptureConnection class so you shouldn't cast it to AnyObject:

```
// Change first line to this
for port in connection.inputPorts { 
   // Also to make it more secure (and avoid force casting)
   if let port = port as? AVCaptureInputPort, 
        port.mediaType == AVMediaTypeVideo {

       // You can delete force casting also here
       videoConnection = connection
       break connectionloop
   }
}
```